# Istio: how to find a pod that handles the request?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to understand which pod actually serves the requests that are routed by Istio.

There are quite a number of virtual services so iterating over them one by one is too time-consuming. Anyway, I did that and didn't find the actual Kubernetes Service/Pod that handles the request.

With Istio, is there a way to ask which pod handles the request coming to `/pipeline/apis/v1beta1/runs`, for instance? In other words, find a pod given a route.

I found that with `istioctl` there is a way to find out which routes are handled by a given Service/Pod as [described here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl-describe/) (actually it doesn't seem to give more info that's already in the virtualservice definition). I need exactly the opposite - given a route to find a pod.

Comment: You could use [istio distributed tracing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/) like jaeger, to trace all requests and find the one you need. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: @Matt thank you for this suggestion, it's good. I just thought that there should be a simple tool to just run the evaluation of istio's VirtualService routing rules. istio does it already for each incoming request, I think it makes sense to provide this functionality for debugging purposes.